# error:Failed to resolve: com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2

Tags: java, android, ide

the module cannot be downloaded
Mac operating system
error:Failed to resolve: com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHhq6.png)

I used IP change software as well as DNS change software
But the problem was not solved

Comment: That library has not been updated in over four years. Please consider using something newer and actively maintained, such as OkHttp. Otherwise, add `jcenter()` to your list of repositories in Gradle.

Comment: Why do you want to use a public library that's not actively maintained and wehn there are better alternatives available such as `Retrofit`? If you really insist on using this lib, please use `jitpack` repository as mentioned by someone in this [thread](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking/issues/554#issuecomment-854631396).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.